# How to fix query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a view table in mysql i am facing a problem in mysql query

```
CREATE VIEW `vwStockin` AS 
SELECT id
     , refno
     , pcode
     , qty 
     , sdate
     , stockinby 
  FROM tbl_product
  JOIN tbl_stockin 
    ON tbl_product.pcode = tbl_stockin.pcode
```

It shows the following error:
**1052 - Column 'pcode' in field list is ambiguous**

Comment: Just remove the ambiguity. E.g. tbl_product.pcode. Incidentally, to my way of thinking, VIEWS serve almost no useful purpose in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the table name to the columns with same name  present in both the joined  table

```
    CREATE VIEW `vwStockin` 
    AS SELECT id
             ,refno
             ,tbl_product.pcode
             ,qty
             ,sdate
             ,stockinby 
    FROM `tbl_product` 
    INNER JOIN tbl_stockin ON `tbl_product`.pcode = `tbl_stockin`.pcode
```

generally is better use a fully qualified name for joined tables and use alias for a better reading eg:

```
    CREATE VIEW `vwStockin` 
    AS SELECT p.id
             ,p.refno
             ,p.pcode
             ,s.qty
             ,s.sdate
             ,s.stockinby 
    FROM `tbl_product` p 
    INNER JOIN tbl_stockin  s ON p.pcode =  s.pcode
```

Comment: show me the exact error message  ..  (have you others column with the  same name??)

Comment: "It's not working" is a nearly useless statement to make to someone who is trying to help but cannot see your screen. Why is it not working? What happens that means it differed from your expectations? Does your computer explode when you press F5? There was a tiny typo in the answer when I first looked at it- it's now fixed but I would genuinely expect anyone to have a go at fixing it up themselves rather than just outright complaining they hadn't been handed a perfect solution to their problem

Comment: CREATE VIEW `vwStockin` 
    AS SELECT p.id
             ,p.refno
             ,p.pcode
             ,s.qty
             ,s.sdate
             ,s.stockinby 
    FROM `tbl_product` p 
    INNER JOIN tbl_stockin  p ON p.pcode =  s.pcode
MySQL said: Documentation

#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'p'

Comment: answer updated   ..  tbl_stockin  s ...but be sure that each  column have the proper table alias ..  ( i don't know your table schema and my is a suggestion)  ..

Comment: I have two table (tbl_product) and (tbl_stockin) and join them in one table using VIEW. Inside the `tbl_product` i have ,pcode barcode, pdesc, bid, ,cid, price, qty in tbl_stock in i have id, refno, pcode, qty, sdate, stockinby

Comment: I'm 99% sure the answer above should be working as intended at least in the state it is now (after editing). Use the second query he describes and you should be fine.

Comment: The first example in the answer still has a typo: `p.id` as `p` is not an alias in that one.

Comment: @iakobski  -- thanks answer updated  remove the p alias in first query  ..

Comment: @RealName123  .. yourl last comment is not clear  ..  you have (another ) error or the query work ???